# How can i get the output as just the city name instead of whole address in my App when using Google API?

Tags: android, google-api, google-places-api

Even when the user search for any locality in a city, the output should be name of the city.

```
package com.example.rajat.location;

import android.content.Intent; import android.os.Bundle; import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; import android.util.Log; import android.view.View; import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException; import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesRepairableException; import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status; import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place; import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocomplete;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    /*
     * In this method, Start PlaceAutocomplete activity
     * PlaceAutocomplete activity provides--
     * a search box to search Google places
     */
    public void findPlace(View view) {
        try {
            Intent intent =
                    new PlaceAutocomplete
                            .IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN)
                            .build(this);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
        }
    }

    // A place has been received; use requestCode to track the request.
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // retrive the data by using getPlace() method.
                Place place = PlaceAutocomplete().getPlace(this, data);
                Log.e("Tag", "Place: " + place.getAddress() + place.getPhoneNumber());

                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.searched_address))
                        .setText(place.getName()+",\n"+
                                place.getAddress() +"\n" + place.getPhoneNumber());

            } else if (resultCode == PlaceAutocomplete.RESULT_ERROR) {
                Status status = PlaceAutocomplete.getStatus(this, data);
                // TODO: Handle the error.
                Log.e("Tag", status.getStatusMessage());

            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // The user canceled the operation.
            }
        }
    } }
```

Comment: You get back a JSON string, no? See: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a key specific to the Google Places API to retrieve the city name from your JSON response object.

This link shows the JSON response you are getting back (the key value pairs) 
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details

Inspect your JSON response object (which i believe is your "Place" object).

Run a debug statement on this line of code. Place place = PlaceAutocomplete().getPlace(this, data);

Once you know the key for City, grab the City value and only populate your UI with the City value.

Comment: i couldn't get the key for city as the whole address gets stored in the key- **Address**. There is no key for separate city or State.